# Do I need to install PHP, MySQL, and something like XAMP, if I already have an IDE, a webhost, and FTP client?

Tags: php, mysql, installation, web-hosting

It seems like there are two ways to go, and the determining factor is whether you want to host on your own computer, or through a webhost.

If I have an IDE, a webhost server I subscribe to, and an FTP client to transfer my files to the server, then I don't need to install PHP, MySQL, and XAMP, right?

I know XAMP allows me make my computer website server.

When I install PHP, am I installing the intepreter for my computer/server to parse the .php files? (and same for MySQL?)

If I pay for web hosting, then their servers already have PHP and MySQL parsers, and all I need to do is upload my text files, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ftp`is a protocol from the stone ages. It should not be used any more, since it is a nightmare for all firewall administrators and offers no security whatsoever. Use the modern replacement `sftp` or directly its base protocol `ssh`. They offer strong encryption and a key based authentication instead of weak passwords.

Comment: oh. I installed filezilla. i'm not sure what protocol it exactly is.

Comment: Then _maybe_ you want to check it in Filezilla?

Comment: lol, i like how you took the time to emphasize "maybe"

So apparently you can choose either, and Filezlila is just a program that supports either.

It was FTP. When i select SFTP, it does not allow me to connect to my server anymore.

Comment: Well yes, that is because ftp is served by an ftp server and sftp is served by an sftp server (ssh server).

Comment: my host, hostgator says it supports both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U just cant simply put the files in server without developing them.and if you want to develop any website or any webapp then u need to make your system a local server where you can execute your server side languages like php.XAMP is a short form for mysql,apache and php for windows.and 'website server' is not the proper word.use LOCALHOST instead because only u will have access to your server unless you are connected via LAN or WAN.so i can summarize the above in few points keeping in mind that you want to develop your website.

```
step 1:install XAMP
step 2:develop and test your scripts.
Step 3:if everything works fine than host your site in the webserver for everybody to see it.
```

Comment: Sorry, although there is truth in what you wrote this cannot be left uncommented: 1. it certainly is possible to do remote web development. It may not be elegant end effecitive, but certainly possible. For example you can create an are (path) that is blocked for general usage where only you have web access to. Combining that with an IDE that works network transparent (that can open remote files via any protocol just like local files) you can do development. 2. when you install an http server on your local system you can request it under the `localhost` shortcut, but it stays a `webserver`.

Comment: @arkascha you are absolutely write but i wrote the above points keeping in mind that the user who posted the question is begginer in web development so for a beginner remote web development is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, that is fine with me. Though I have different experiences. I found that many newbies are _less_ confused when developing in only _one_ environment and that _less_ typical problems arise like confusion between remote and local access if development is done in a realistic environment instead of the simplified local system setup. The main problem: you need a really network transparent system / set of applications. That rules out MS-Windows.

Comment: @arkascha again you made a nice point but how i look at it is for the newbies it would be good if they start with the basics and after that they can experiment with whatever they want and personally i never liked windows because of their lack in security features.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it with that. Though: please read again through your own last comment: first you confirm that what I write is true, then you just wipe that away and say the exact opposite makes more sense. Sorry, that is illogical :-) Have fun!

Comment: @arkascha there is just a little bit difference in our opinion and that doesnot make any of your points invalid.:) have a nice day ! +1 for your points.

Comment: so you choose between local host or external host.

I just wanted to clear up whether having both were redundant. I have a strong feeling that is the case, but just wanted to confirm.

you either host on your local machine, or through your paid hosting service. So they are mutually exclusive, and you don't need both.

However, I'm guessing having localhosting is useful for testing things before committing to be live on your paid hosting server.

Comment: "U just cant simply put the files in server without developing them."

What do you mean? of course i would be uploading files that have code in them (i.e. "developed"). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @gwho5150 ya that is what i meant if you want to put a developed file in the server than u need to develop it and for starters u have to develop it in your local machine(lets not talk about remote development) and for that you need XAMP,WAMP or LAMP,its up to you.i hope yo are getting my point.have a nice day :)

Comment: I fully agree with:

" I found that many newbies are less confused when developing in only one environment and that less typical problems arise like confusion between remote and local access if development is done in a realistic environment instead of the simplified local system setup. "

I think I have a perfectly fine handle on things, in part thanks to you guys. apache is a localhost, which can execute server side languages, and is visible only to me.

In contrast, uploading files to a webhosting company's server is for live viewing for everyone to see.

Comment: @gwho5150 i think u got my point.and if you are satisfied with my answer feel free to accept it :)

Comment: So IDE is not necessary.

IDE lets you do both localhosting and remote development?

Comment: @gwho5150 first tell me which server side language you are using?

Comment: im using php.

My IDE is netbeans, but I'm not using that currently. I'm confused on how IDEs work (and also Netbeans's documentation is pretty horrid).

I am just using XAMPP to test how it runs, and when it's good, I use Filezilla to upload to my server.

Comment: ya IDE's have inbuilt servers.

Comment: and ya you can also do remote development with netbeans.

Comment: i think this link will be helpful to you https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html